# ¿Como detener mediaplayer desde cualquier activity al salir de la aplicación?

Tags: java, android-studio, mediaplayer

No tengo mucha experiencia en el desarrollo de aplicaciones, espero alguien pueda ayudarme ya que tengo varios días, rompiéndome la cabeza y no encuentro la respuesta.

Estoy desarrollando una app, la cual consta de varias Actividades  y estoy tratando de poner una canción la cual pueda recorrer todas las actividades sin ser interrumpida, pero al momento de salir de la aplicación desde cualquier activity finalice el proceso de media player, ya que hasta el momento he logrado reproducir la cancion en todas las actividades pero al bloquear o salir de la app se sigue escuchando en 2 plano.

Intente hacerlo creando una clase solo para media player y tambien como un servicio, agregándolo a mi `manifest.xml` pero me encuentro en las mismas condiciones.

Les dejo mi codigo:

```
public class AudioPlayer {

    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private static SoundPool soundPool;
    public static boolean isplayingAudio=false;

    public static void playAudio(Context c,int id){
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c,id);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            isplayingAudio=true;
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

    }

    public static void stopAudio(){
        isplayingAudio=false;
        mediaPlayer.stop();

    }
}
```

Actividad donde ejecuta la clase:

```
    public class splash extends Activity {


    private final int DURACION_SPLASH = 4000;
    public MediaPlayer reproduvtor;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AudioPlayer.playAudio(this, R.raw.hpt);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                Intent intent = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            };
        }, DURACION_SPLASH);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

deberias crear el metodo onDestroy y dentro de este llamar a tu metodo stopAudio()

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopAudio();
    }
```